# javascript regex over getAttribute match?

Tags: javascript, regex, getattribute

everyone, 
I would like to query or save a part of the page.

But I don't know if the coder works. 
can somebody tell if it can work like this?

```
window._activeShopName='';
window._thisButtonHandler=this.getAttribute('data-shop-name').match(/"(.*?)"/);
    if (window._thisButtonHandler) window._activeShopName=window._thisButtonHandler[1];
    return true;
```

I have the problem with the match or better said regex? 
HTML-Code

```
  <button data-product-id="13992128" data-offer-id="31702737" data-bid-id="1387" data-bid-place="1" data-rank="3" data-shop-name="google.com" class="offer__to-seller-btn js-product-call-to-action js-redirect-click sl-redirect-click">More</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want just want the value of `data-shop-name`. If that's the only button ***or*** the first button on the page, there's 3 ways to get it's value.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

var x1 = btn.dataset.shopName;
var x2 = btn.dataset['shopName'];
var z = btn.getAttribute('data-shop-name');

console.log(x1);
console.log(x2);
console.log(z);
```

```html
<button data-product-id="13992128" data-offer-id="31702737" data-bid-id="1387" data-bid-place="1" data-rank="3" data-shop-name="google.com" class="offer__to-seller-btn js-product-call-to-action js-redirect-click sl-redirect-click">More</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you want, but I'll try to explain what is your code doing at this point:

1. From `getAttribute` you will receive a string, but quotation marks are not a part of this string (so you should probably remove them from RegExp).
2. `.*?` means `match any character, 0 or more times, ungreedy`. So, if it can match zero symbols and it must be ungreedy, then it matches exactly zero symbols.